# Writing to a div from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a div box where it displays a randomized quote generated in the javascript, but it does not display when I run the code.

My html is simply

```
<div id="quotebox"></div>
```

my javascript is

```
var quotes = new Array()
quotes[0]="Simplicity is the ultimate sopistication";
quotes[1]="While I thought that I was learning how to live, I have been learning how to die.";
quotes[2]="The greatest deception men suffer is from their own opinions.";
quotes[3]="Art is never finished, only abandoned";
quotes[4]="Iron rusts from disuse; water loses its purity from stagnation. Even so does inaction sap the vigor of the mind.";

var randQuote=Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
function showQuote(){
    document.getElementById("quotebox").innerHTML = quotes[randQuote];
}
```

Am I just making a silly mistake or what is going on? I've tried several different things now and it still doesn't display to the div.

Comment: Are you calling showQuote() anywhere? Or try checking your quotes variable to make sure it has the data in it.

Comment: I've tried calling it both in the <body> and <div> but nothing happens. What do you mean check the quotes variable?

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling showQuote(); Here is the working JS fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/9bmAN/`

```
var quotes = new Array()
quotes[0]="Simplicity is the ultimate sopistication";
quotes[1]="While I thought that I was learning how to live, I have been learning how to die.";
quotes[2]="The greatest deception men suffer is from their own opinions.";
quotes[3]="Art is never finished, only abandoned";
quotes[4]="Iron rusts from disuse; water loses its purity from stagnation. Even so does inaction sap the vigor of the mind.";

var randQuote=Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
function showQuote(){
    document.getElementById("quotebox").innerHTML = quotes[randQuote];
}

showQuote()
```

Comment: what is this comment for?

Comment: i deleted it..got mistakenly posted here. Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an element (div, td, whatever) with the id: "quotebox":

```
function showQuote(){
   var quotes = new Array()
quotes[0]="Simplicity is the ultimate sopistication";
quotes[1]="While I thought that I was learning how to live, I have been learning how to die.";
quotes[2]="The greatest deception men suffer is from their own opinions.";
quotes[3]="Art is never finished, only abandoned";
quotes[4]="Iron rusts from disuse; water loses its purity from stagnation. Even so does inaction sap the vigor of the mind.";

var randQuote=Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
    document.getElementById("quotebox").innerHTML = quotes[randQuote];
}
</script>
<body onload="showQuote();">
<div id="quotebox">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){   
    var quotes = new Array()
    quotes[0]="Simplicity is the ultimate sopistication";
    quotes[1]="While I thought that I was learning how to live, I have been learning how to die.";
    quotes[2]="The greatest deception men suffer is from their own opinions.";
    quotes[3]="Art is never finished, only abandoned";
    quotes[4]="Iron rusts from disuse; water loses its purity from stagnation. Even so does inaction sap the vigor of the mind.";

    var randQuote=Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
        document.getElementById("quotebox").innerHTML = quotes[randQuote];

};     
  </script>

<body >
<div id="quotebox"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nothing is still being displayed in the div.

Comment: Above code works fine :) Check the update! use window.onload()

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script>
var quotes = new Array()
quotes[0]="Simplicity is the ultimate sopistication";
quotes[1]="While I thought that I was learning how to live, I have been learning how to die.";
quotes[2]="The greatest deception men suffer is from their own opinions.";
quotes[3]="Art is never finished, only abandoned";
quotes[4]="Iron rusts from disuse; water loses its purity from stagnation. Even so does inaction sap the vigor of the mind.";

var randQuote=Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
function showQuote(){
    document.getElementById("quotebox").innerHTML = quotes[randQuote];
}
</script>
<body onload="showQuote()">
    <div id="quotebox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code runs well on my browser. May be some problem with your browser.